# What does it mean for a line bundle to be $n-$very ample?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

I know what a very ample line bundle is, but cannot find a definition of an $n-$very ample line bundle, where $n$ is some integer

Comment: Perhaps $L^n$ is very ample? Or $L$ defines an embedding into $\Bbb P^n$? Does any of these two options make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one notion that goes by the name "$k$-very ample":

**Definition** [[Beltrametti–Sommese 1991](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1273371)]**.** Let $L$ be a line bundle on a variety $X$. We say that $L$ is *$k$-very ample* for $k \ge 0$ if for every zero-dimensional subscheme $Z$ of length $k+1$, the restriction map
$$H^0(X,L) \longrightarrow H^0(X,L \otimes \mathcal{O}_Z)$$
is surjective.

The intuition is that if $L$ is $k$-very ample for $k > 1$, then it induces a higher-order embedding of $X$. You might imagine that there could be other ways to capture this notion, and indeed, there are many higher-order ampleness conditions you can put on a line bundle; see [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/199092/33088) for a summary. The first place where such ideas appeared is probably [[Beltrametti–Francia–Sommese 1989](http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-89-05819-5)].

Some properties you might expect about $k$-very ampleness are rather difficult to prove: for example, it is non-trivial that the tensor product of a $k$-very ample line bundle and an $l$-very ample line bundle is $k+l$-very ample [[Hinohara–Takahashi–Terakawa 2004](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-04-07648-8)].

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to be the notion I need